# How can you ignore invalid parameters when deserializing object from Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying deserialize object which might have invalid schema. In that case I would like all invalid parameters to be ignored. The idea is I don't really know what changes in json will be made and I would like my app to work as long as it possible. I have all classes desribed in following fashion:

```
[DataContract]
public class SampleObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public InnerObject Inner {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? Value1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? Value3 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double? Value4 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value5 { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    public class InnerObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The deserialization logic:

```
const string JsonObject = @"{
     Value12: 123,
     Value1: 'abc',
     Value2: 'abc',
     Value3: 'abc',
     Value4: 'abc',
     Inner: {
         StringValue: 'abc'
     }
}";

var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterObject>(JsonObject);
```

Deserialization of course fails, because "Could not convert string to integer: abc. Path 'Value3', line 5, position 30.". However I would like deserialization to succeed with values of all invalid fields (Value1, Value3 and Value4) to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set up an error handler that ignores exceptions that occur when deserializing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = (obj, args) =>
    {
        var context = args.ErrorContext;

        context.Handled = true;        
    }
};

var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleObject>(JsonObject, settings);
```

This marks *all* exceptions as "handled," which is probably unwise. A better choice might be to examine the property that failed (`context.Member`), as well as the exception (`context.Error`) type to determine whether this is an exception you want to ignore or not.

Comment: It definitely solved the serialization problems, but resulting object is empty. It looks like it's invoked once for object, and then interrupted.

Comment: @Darnok: What do you mean by *resulting object is empty*? Is `a` in the code above `null`? Or are all of the properties `null`?

Comment: I have an resulting object (with inner object) but all the values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) are null and property of inner object (StringValue) is also null

Comment: @Darnok: Gotcha. For the example you posted, it's working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FpqVce

Comment: Ok, got it - I hadn't fill all the fields with [DataMember] attribute correctly, therefore valid fields wasn't deserialized at all (since no DataMember attribute). Now it's working perfeclty (thanks to your code) here is my (almost) working solution: http://pastebin.com/tsE425s1